# spark 'join with condition' versus 'join with filter', which is better?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to join two dataframes based on some condition. **Which of the two approaches has better performance characteristics?**

**first approach**

```py
df1.join(df2, (df1("numer") === df2("numer")), "full")
```

**second approach**

```py
df1.join(df2, how="full").filter(df1("numer") === df2("numer"))
```

Comment: obviously first approach always . because join is more focused

Comment: the second approach would use a column called `full` as join column. Do you probably mean a  [crossJoin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#crossJoin(right:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)?

Comment: @werner no, its not crossJoin its full join (you can say full outer join) and in the second approach  argument like (dataframe = df2 , joinType = "full" )